# How can I access item description from my Stripe webhook?

Tags: python-3.x, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe Checkout (Client & Server Integration) and I want to be able to access the item description from my web hook.

```py
session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
      payment_method_types=['card'],
      line_items=[{
        'name': 'Name of Product',
        'description': description,
        'amount': 30,
        'currency': 'gbp',
        'quantity': 1,
      }],
      success_url='https://www.website.uk/success',
      cancel_url='https://www.website.uk/cancel',
    )
```

Description is a variable that holds my item description.

My web hook looks like this (straight from docs):

```py
@require_POST
@csrf_exempt
def my_webhook_view(request):

  payload = request.body
  sig_header = request.META['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE']
  event = None

  try:
    event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(
      payload, sig_header, endpoint_secret
    )
  except ValueError as e:
    # Invalid payload
    return HttpResponse(status=400)
  except stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError as e:
    # Invalid signature
    return HttpResponse(status=400)

  # Handle the checkout.session.completed event
  if event['type'] == 'payment_intent.succeeded':
    session = event['data']['object']

    # Fulfill the purchase...


  return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

My question is, how can I access my "description" variable from within the web hook? (Will be accessing it after # Fulfill the purchase)

I can see it is part of the session object (https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object) but I'm not sure how to access it?

Have tried:

```
description = session['display_items']['custom']['description']
```

But I'm getting a key_error on display_items even though it is listed in the docs as part of the session object.

Comment: your `session` is coming from `event.data.object`, but it is not the `session` object and so your approach didn't work.

Comment: Thanks - yes I see ```session``` is actually the payment intent object now. According to the docs "the web hook payload includes the checkout session object" but I can't see it in ```request.body```.

Comment: I have fixed it - I had not configured the "checkout.session.completed" event to be sent to my Webhooks. I've now done that and can access it with ```if event['type'] == 'checkout.session.completed':
      checkout_session = event['data']['object']```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue which may help others who end up here; the length of the line_items array is 1 and the object which holds the properties is at index [0], therefore:

```
session.line_items[0].description
```

should give one access to the properties and values